# Construir GUI para Windows sem utilizar Windows API

Tags: c++, gui, winapi

Eu tenho procurado pela internet uma forma de construir interfaces gráficas para o windows sem necessariamente usar o Windows API.

Eu programo em C# e para tal, tenho como solução o WPF. Porém, não consegui achar nenhuma solução em C++.

O meu objetivo é criar uma GUI tal como os softwares Popcorn, Ccleaner, dentro outros. Neles, dá para perceber que a interface não foi feita (ao menos é o que eu acho) em windows form e nem baseada nas janelas de outros sistemas, como poderia ser um programa para linux ou MacOS X, o que traz um noção de design sofisticado e diferente.

Não sei se deu pra ser muito claro, mas o ponto é que há programas com interfaces "padrão", são aqueles que possuem uma interface parecida com os elementos gráficos do  próprio sistema operacional (janelas, botões, caixa de texto, etc) E há programas que possuem um estilo de interface própria. Queria uma solução para C++ que me desse um direcionamento pra isso.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você está a procura de um gerenciador de janelas cross plataform para sua aplicação? Se este for o caso eu lhe recomendo o GTK, utilizei bastante com C#, mas seu funcionamento é o mesmo para as demais linguagens.http://www.gtkmm.org/pt_BR/index.html

Comment: Na verdade, a princípio, o meu interesse era realmente descobrir uma solução que me desse uma interface mais personalizada e não tanto baseada nas janelas do windows.

Comment: Eu acho que mais do que não usar diretamente o esquema do sistema operacional o seu desejo é ter uma janela com um estilo totalmente próprio, independente do estilo nativo (dado os exemplos do PopcornTime e CCleaner). Nesse caso, eu iria pela resposta já dada, usando Qt. Você pode simplesmente ["desligar" a renderização nativa da janela (usando `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) e então desenhar a sua do jeito que quiser. Eis um exemplo em Qt, com uma janela semi-transparente: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=ARGB-Widgets

Comment: Outro exemplo mais completo (a página está em Francês, mas nada que o Google Translation não ajude): http://qt.developpez.com/tutoriels/braindeadbzh/customwindow/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se estes softwares não foram feitos com .NET, e até onde eu sei não foram, realmente eles não usam Windows Forms, que nada mais é que uma camada em cima da API do Windows.

Quando você quer manipular janelas no sistema operacional não tem muito como escapar da API de janelas dele. Até que ponto vai usar todos os recursos ou só os principais e fazer o resto na mão é uma decisão sua ou da biblioteca que deseja usar.

A maioria dos programadores preferem usar bibliotecas que facilitam o uso da API do sistema operacional.

De fato se sua intenção é fazer uma aplicação que rode em mais do que uma plataforma existem duas alternativas: criar um código para manipular as telas em cada plataforma ou usar uma biblioteca que consiga abstrair uma boa parte delas.

Se vai criar um sistema de GUI para cada plataforma algumas opções seria a [MFC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160) para Windows, [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) para Linux ou [Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html) para MacOS.

Existem outras opções principalmente para Windows, mas todo mundo reclama que nenhuma é boa o suficiente. E elas funcionam direitinho mas em geral são bibliotecas difíceis de lidar.

É possível usar o GTK em outras plataformas mas o resultado não fica bom. É necessário um *binding* já que esta biblioteca foi escrita em C.

É quase impraticável usar Cocoa diretamente em C++.

Se a opção é criar um único sistema para todas elas as melhores opções parecem ser [WxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) e [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

A primeira usa bastante os recursos nativos mas não é tão simples trabalhar com ela e nem sempre o resultado é adequado. O visual funciona bem mas a experiência deixa a desejar. Já vi alguns relatos de *bugs* que nunca são solucionados.

A segunda nem sempre consegue resultado visual perfeito mas é mais simples fazer tudo funcionar em todas as plataformas. Ela ainda permite fazer as aplicações para as 3 principais plataformas de dispositivos móveis. Claro que aproveitar telas para desktop em mobile não é algo que costuma dar certo. Ela é considerada nativa no Linux e o visual para Windows é muito bem reproduzido, se bobear tanto quanto ou mais que o WPF que também não é perfeito.

Em quase todas elas é possível fazer um visual personalizado que fuja do padrão do sistema operacional. Mas o problema é se mudar o comportamento, a experiência geral. Por melhor que seja a usabilidade em uma plataforma, quando ela é aplicada em outra, não costuma dar muito certo.

Mesmo que queira usar só para Windows, como demostra o título da pergunta, provavelmente preferirá uma biblioteca de mais alto nível, como a Qt. Pela flexibilidade dela, parece ser o mais próximo do que você deseja. Mas não acredite na minha palavra, pesquise mais.

A Qt permite fazer o visual da aplicação ficar da maneira que você quiser. Ela permite que todo o seu desenho seja personalizado.

Optar por MFC, [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library) ou [WTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library). que são opções oficiais ou quase oficiais da Microsoft não é fácil. Alguns acham que a API pura Win32 é até mais fácil :)

Existem outras opções mas poucas pessoas utilizam: [eGUI](http://torjo.com/egui/), [Ultimate++](http://www.ultimatepp.org/), [SmartWin](http://smartwin.sourceforge.net/).

Existe ainda a biblioteca [VCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library) do Builder, mas só funciona com compiladores da Embarcadero.

A lista não termina aqui, a quantidade de opções é impressionante.

Esta é base para você pesquisar mais e ver o que atende sua necessidade. Mas já aviso que nenhuma é perfeita.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resposta bem consistente! Dei uma olhada aqui no Qt. A nível de personalização de interface, realmente me parece muito boa. Acaba até me lembrando um pouco do WPF, por usar a linguagem QML pra fazer a interface. Muito obrigado pelo direcionamento.

Comment: A biblioteca para se usar em um sistema para Linux não depende da interface instalada no sistema? Por exemplo, eu uso o Gnome, que é baseado no GTK.

Comment: Depende, a biblioteca precisa estar instalada, mas o fato de você usar Gnome não significa que programas escritos com a Qt não vão rodar. A biblioteca de GUI é uma coisa, o gerenciador de desktop é outra. O Gnome é baseado no GTK, os programas que rodam nele não precisam ser.

Comment: Dá pra ter as 2 bibliotecas (e várias outras) rodando em paralelo. Meu celular é um N900 da Nokia, os apps originais são baseados em GTK, mas tem muita coisa em Qt rodando. Inclusive, os demos do pyQt rodam perfeitamente nele.